# Method inside class is not getting executed in unit test

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js, chai

I have a class which contains methods.Now after initializing the class i want to invoke the methods but my test flow is not to the method and getting error like `Uncaught error outside test suite`.Below is my code

```
describe('Test Stu positive', () => {
it("Test Stu positive", (done) => {
    const stuDetails = new masterDetails(getdetails);
    expect(stuDetails.retrieveStudent(res => {
        console.log(res);
        done()
    }))
});
});
```

Now, in the above code i am not able to print `console.log(res);`. What i am doing wrong?

Comment: would you post the master detail source?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you are using Mocha as your testing framework and looks like the error is not being handled by mocha, because is an asynchronous operation and you are not passing the error to the done callback method as described in the [mocha documentation](https://mochajs.org/#asynchronous-code)

it is really hard to tell how your function works, if it returns a promise or if it just uses a callback and the error is handled inside the function, so I can't provide you a code example on how to accomplish this. if you mind providing your function declaration I can update my answer with an example solution.